# Using parameters in files that get rendered by git(hub)

Tags: git, github, templates, version-control, github-actions

I remember that with VCS you could add template codes in you file that the system substitutes for the actual values.

For example you could have

```
Version: $$version$$
Date $$date$$
```

That would, when deployed become:

```
Version: 3.1.4
Date 01-02-2023
```

I'm looking for something likewise in git or github.

I'd like to automatically generate an about dialog in my program by doing the following:

```
print("Program Name")
print("Version: $$tag$$")
if ("develop" == "$$branch$$") {
    print("Commit: $$commit$$")
}
```

Or something like this.

Maybe github actions might provide this, but I'm not well versed in that functionality.

Comment: Could you maybe describe your use-case? For example I fail to see how this is related to GitHub Actions.

Comment: What language is that in that code snippet? Can you not use its functionality to read values from environment variables?

Comment: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Does_Git_have_keyword_expansion.3F , https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_ident , https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion